# Only run WayPoints if viewport width is greater than 1000px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-waypoints, slick.js

Is there a way to only run WayPoints when the viewport is greater than a certain width? Preferably checking if that width changes on resize?

Normally I'd just leave this but I have 4 sections and when they come into view I add a class of `.in-view` to them so I can animate the divs within. The problem is (I think) that on mobile my sections display in a slideshow (Slick slider) so I have the same animation/transition styling on `.slick-current` and sometimes they don't work, which is likely because it's setting the elements to `.in-view` still?

This is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var waypoints = document.querySelectorAll('.showcase__item');
    for (var i = waypoints.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var waypoint = new Waypoint({
            element: waypoints[i],
            handler: function(direction) {
                this.element.classList.toggle('in-view');
            },
            offset: '60%',
        });
    }
});
```

Is this possible ...is it even a good idea? Not sure how stressful this would be on performance?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know really this plugin but it would be possible using `window.matchMedia().addListener()` method, it would be better than binding to window resize event. Then you could enabling/disabling waypoint plugin. By the way, you should initialize plugin using jQuery's way.

The following code hasn't been tested:

```
var widthMatch = window.matchMedia("(min-width:1000px)");
var waypoints;

widthMatch.addListener(function(e) {
  switchWayPoints(e.matches);
});

function switchWayPoints(enable) {
  waypoints[enable ? "enableAll" : "disableAll"]();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  waypoints = $('.showcase__item').waypoint(function(direction) {
    // -> Seem strange to call it here without any direction check?! ->$(this).toggleClass('in-view');
  }, {
    offset: '60%'
  });

  switchWayPoints(widthMatch.matches);
});
```

Comment: I'll try and knock up a CodePen, would this allow me to remove the classes when the browser is below 1000px? I'm interested by your comment on the other answer and I am a bit concerned my page is getting a bit heavy! I could specify the same styles on both `slick-current` and `in-view` but only for set media-queries but that seems like a lot of work and I'd need to maintain two lots of code ...that said, if it's going to perform better?

Comment: The thing is `switchWayPoints()` method will be called only if window is passing 1000px gap (over and lower, both), unlike using window resize event. So ya, it will perform better. Now regarding: `"I could specify the same styles on both slick-current and in-view but only for set media-queries but that seems like a lot of work"` **->**  i don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I might need to make a CodePen but basically I animate  (transition) a load of divs using `in-view`. Once that’s added I change opacity, position, size etc. On mobile these Div’s become slides in a slideshow, so I apply the same transitions to a `slick-current` class. So I think they kinky clash and “in-view” affects the animations on mobile as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [`$(window).resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) and [`$(window).width();`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) .
[`$(window).resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes and [`$(window).width();`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) gets the current width of the window. Here is the snippet of the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function () {
        width=$(window).width();
        if (width > 1000){
            var waypoints = document.querySelectorAll('.showcase__item');
            for (var i = waypoints.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var waypoint = new Waypoint({
                    element: waypoints[i],
                    handler: function(direction) {
                        this.element.classList.toggle('in-view');
                    },
                    offset: '60%',
                });
            }
        } else {
            // Your logic when the screen size is less then 1000 px.
            if ($("#someID").hasClass("classname")) {
                $("#someID").removeClass("classname"); 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, I'll give this a try! Will it remove the classes if they've already been added? I guess not but it's no biggie!

Comment: Each time the window is resized (or any element inside DOM) and for each pixel (with some padding but...), this event will be fired. It means in this case if the window is resized from 1020 to 1040 e.g, it will be called near 20 times, even if the window width was already over 1000px. So it will reinitialize plugin 20 times for nothing. It cannot be used there

Comment: I was going to say that worked great but the class didn't seem to do anything until I opened the console, then it all worked as it did before. When I closed it everything disappeared again - a lot of divs have `opacity: 0;` so they only show when the class is added. :/